# It is estimated that 15% of all Lakes College students walk to college. A random sample of 7 Lakes College students is chosen.

Tags: probability

It is estimated that 15% of all Lakes College students walk to college. A random sample of 7 Lakes College students is chosen.

a)
Calculate the probability that none of the 7 students in the sample walk to college.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe $0.85^7$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that none of them walk to college is $$(1-15\%)^7 \approx32\%,$$
since the probability that one of them does not walk to college is $1-\mathsf P(\text{walks})$.

Comment: what about the probability that at least 3 of the 7 students walk to college? would that be 15%^3 ?